# How can I change the color of my line graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

There seems to be an issue for me to specify the color. When I do color by rowid it gives me a default blue color that is shades of the same color that I don't know how to change. I want each line to have a unique color. How can I do so?

```
plot <- ggplot(data=viewership, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=rowid)) + 
          geom_line(aes(colour=rowid, group=rowid)) + 
          geom_point()
```

Comment: What do the data look like? can use use dput() to provide enough to replicate your problem?

Comment: Sounds like ggplot sees your rowid as a continuous variable so it plots color to a continuous gradient.  What happens if you treat it as a discrete, categorical variable, i.e. `as.factor(rowid)`?  Do you get unique, discrete colors?

Comment: Are you suggesting I pass as.factor to geomline colour?

Comment: Changing your data as suggested in the answer is good. If you don't want to to that for some reason, then `colour = factor(rowid)` inside `aes()` should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `rowid` into factor,

```
viewership$rowid <- as.factor(viewership$rowid)
```

Re-run your code, you will get your plot.